# name 'Scatter3d' is not defined

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create a 3D graph using plotly but I am getting the error:

> Scatter 3D not defined

I am using jupyterlab and am accessing it through anaconda, every thing is updated including the plotly files.

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
​
​
trace1=Scatter3d(x=Xe,
               y=Ye,
               z=Ze,
               mode='lines',
               line=Line(color='rgb(125,125,125)', width=1),
               hoverinfo='none'
               )
​
trace2=Scatter3d(x=Xn,
               y=Yn,
               z=Zn,
               mode='markers',
               name='actors',
               marker=Marker(symbol='dot',
                             color=eigen,
                             size=6,colorbar=ColorBar(
                title='Colorbar'
            ),
                             colorscale='Viridis',
                             line=Line(color='rgb(158,18,130)', width=0.5)
                             ),
               text=labels,
               hoverinfo='text'
               )
```

When executing the code it stops in trace1 itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the `Scatter3d` method is not defined, in other words, you did not import it or call it properly. Use `print(dir(py))` then `print(dir(go))` to see if `Scatter3d` is in either of those lists. If it is, then you did not call it properly.

Additionally, you could change your import statement from `import plotly.graph_objects as go` to `from plotly.graph_objects import Scatter3d`.